# Blogdown: RMD files in subdirectories do not place HTML in public folder

Tags: r, blogdown

**What Works:**

When I execute `blogdown::serve_site()`, blogdown rebuilds my site and places all html files from my `post` subdirectory in the `/public/post` folder.  This works as expected.

**What Does Not Work:**

If I have created a post in a subdirectory (using `blogdown::new_post()`) -- such as `/exampledir/newpost.rmd`, when I run `blogdown::serve_site()`, the RMD is copied to the `/public/exampledir` folder, but the HTML file does not.

**Question:**

Is this a bug, a feature, or am I doing something else wrong?  Thank you for your help, time, and patience.
Thanks!

**Reproducible Example:**

Creates proper html file in `public/post/testpost.html`

```
blogdown::new_post("testpost", kind = "", open = interactive(), author = getOption("blogdown.author"),
     categories = NULL, tags = NULL, date = Sys.Date(), file = NULL, slug = NULL,
     title_case = getOption("blogdown.title_case"), subdir = getOption("blogdown.subdir",
                                                                       "post"), ext = getOption("blogdown.ext", ".rmd"))
```

Does not create proper html file in `public/exampledir/testpost.html`

```
blogdown::new_post("testpost", kind = "", open = interactive(), author = getOption("blogdown.author"),
     categories = NULL, tags = NULL, date = Sys.Date(), file = NULL, slug = NULL,
     title_case = getOption("blogdown.title_case"), subdir = getOption("blogdown.subdir",
                                                                       "exampledir"), ext = getOption("blogdown.ext", ".rmd"))
```

Comment: In my blogdown setup I have permalinks defined like so:  
```[permalinks]
    post = "/post/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"
    note = "/note/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"
```
Do you have something similar for you `exampledir`?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out.  Where would this permalink be in my blogdown setup?  In the .toml file?

Comment: Yes in `config.toml`